# Data URL images unreadable for IE8

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, data-uri, data-url

I have a 2D barcode generator making some barcodes on the (Java) backend. It gives me data URLs and I set them on the client side using Javascript. All works fine in Chrome, Firefox. But not in IE8 (of course!) although half of the images work and half don't work.

My images are a couple hundred bytes (so much less then 32kb)

Here is an example **not** working in IE8:

`data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABgAAAAYCAAAAADFHGIkAAAACXBIWXMAAAsTAAALEwEAmpwYAAAAEnRFWHRTb2Z0d2FyZQBCYXJjb2RlNEryjnYuAAAAgklEQVR42nVRixKAMAjy/3+a2hBwdVtdD1RELFxOXS6+9v1+F/+ICFs5jpGqsQWSosy3MQbVGSEDC7q4FaQrRiJDepJ1iG2sATggaqkeCc3VqicDDu6omgk1VdmS4W3Uq4sr4hE8llSYKe7GXsTxTPdZTdlyLQA4xrKQOit+Ryv7nwfFATbY5mERHQAAAABJRU5ErkJg`

Here is an example **working** in IE8:

`data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAFMAAABTCAAAAADG2WTcAAAACXBIWXMAACZzAAAmcwHzbHUKAAAAEnRFWHRTb2Z0d2FyZQBCYXJjb2RlNEryjnYuAAABAklEQVR42u2ZwQ7AIAhD+f+f3nbwMGwBl3hYg1xM5ngmUBE3u/abCTHtMTZcS4N3O0z3dNiYg+eeickZ02LMVzRcPJ0DD77zPsw5CQv6BGaYIwkmxo6+/V7S2CKHGShvYaNDmngN+T0TfGk9Y/E0DL4YkxVsWCQsSGGOOjPhHaNVfM5W2YMpMCFu2A3QQyHb722ZkQAT+dLzVJEJvqz4hYqc1H2Y4XHgU0WPCmzFxJhMjrTO00K3uDd7MXm8SSdKc1fej/7LLGTK+8yvPW0jZrGZ15sQXWbUGCTXOXIoiDGLLx3RUN1lOjOzCp5MkzZUmlkIM9JnGs9ezF2mxuz8r2e33b2PHKlEJ4PKAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC`

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Vandeplas/CSu8G). JS fiddle doesn't work so good in IE8 so use [this link](http://fiddle.jshell.net/Vandeplas/CSu8G/show/) to view the result directly.

If you got an idea about the cause of this problem please share :)

Comment: must be an native IE8 bug, it's working for me in IE10 with browsermode IE8.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For some reason the failing base64 decoded `.png` is invalid. If you download the image and re-save it the filesize is different.

I see 237 bytes for the original verses 409 for a re-saved copy.

This can be confirmed with the [`pngcheck`](http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/apps/pngcheck.html) tool.

```
Z:\pngcheck-2.3.0>pngcheck.exe original.png
original.png  EOF while reading CRC value
ERROR: original.png

Z:\pngcheck-2.3.0>pngcheck.exe re-saved.png
OK: re-saved.png (24x24, 32-bit RGB+alpha, non-interlaced, 82.2%).
```

Using the following valid `re-saved.png` base64 encoded data fixes the problem in IE8.

```
background:url(data:image/png;base64,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);
```

I assume Chrome and Firefox are more lenient with the [CRC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_redundancy_check).

Comment: thanx, we'll search for an updated library or try jpg in staid of png. Good tool btw.